# Carregar arquivo através de um edittext

Tags: php, xml

É possivel carregar um arquivo direto já baixado no micro através de um edit ?

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file("clientes.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

No caso o arquivo clientes.xml não seria pré definido no código podendo ser escolhido com nomes diferentes.

Comment: vc dizer já o upload desse xml? ou so apontar o caminho?

Comment: Estou fazendo o upload através do filezilla , e trocando o nome para ser lido , o que gostaria mesmo era pegar o nome direto e gravar no meu banco ( isso eu já faço trocando o nome).

Comment: Da pra fazer sim, vc pode usar [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) para saber se string passada existe como um arquivo.